# Make PApplet Classes communicate with Java code

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to use this SDK (for IntelRealSense Cameras) written in Processing in my Java code. What I did was I took the java source code and made a project with it. So I can run processing sketches directly from my Intellij Java environment using the Processing library.

My question is, can the classes that extend the `PApplet` class and show the sketches interact with other classes in the Java code ( that are not `PApplet`s )? For example, can I create a `Main` class to launch both the `PApplet` sketch and a vanilla Java program as well with them being able to communicate?

The goal is to to integrate this `PApplet` source code into an existing Java project as a module that can transmit information.

All in all, my objective is to : Run concurrently the `PApplet` and my Java program and transmit the camera values from the `PApplet` to my Java Classes.

Is it possible? I mean Processing is Java so It should be, right?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **yes** it's possible.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) is a tutorial on using Processing from Java.

I recommend you read through that, but in summary, you want to do something like this:

```java
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class MySketch extends PApplet{

    public void settings(){
        size(500, 500);
    }

    public void draw(){
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
    }

    public void mousePressed(){
        background(64);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] processingArgs = {"MySketch"};
        MySketch mySketch = new MySketch();
        PApplet.runSketch(processingArgs, mySketch);

        // call whatever Java code you want
    }
}
```

Note that the `main()` method does not have to be in the same class that extends `PApplet`.

This is all "just" Java, so anything that's valid in Java, is valid in a Java program that uses Processing as a Java library.